Mariadb no hacer distincion de mayusculas o minusculas en consultas de nombres de tablas?
Estoy haciendo un respaldo de mi base de datos y migrandola a un servidor nuevo pero he notado que despues de hacer el respaldo.
mysqldump -u miuser -h servidor -p mibase > mibase.db
Y despues restaurarlo en el nuevo servidor:
mariadb -u miuser -h servidorNuevo -p mibase < mibase.db
He notado que el sistema dejo de funcionar, al principio "me alarme" pero el problema es que todos los nombres de las tablas que estan en el servidor antiguo estan n MAYUSCULAS por lo tanto el software hace las consultas usando MAYUSCULAS en los nombres de las tablas. Y al hacer el respaldo y restauracion, los nombre se pusieron en MINUSCULAS , por lo tanto:
Si hago esto, NO busca:

select * from USUARIOS where nombre='Pedro';

Si hago esto, SI busca:

select * from usuarios where nombre='Pedro';

Como puedo pasar de golpe los nombres de las tablas a mayusculas?
o como hago el respaldo para que respete las mayusculas en el nombre de las tablas?

Creo que no hay una forma simple de pasar a mayúsculas todo junto. Aunque si parece haber un parámetro que controla el uso de mayúsculas (lower_case_table_names) y tal vez sea más fácil cambiarlo e importar de nuevo las tablas

@Mateo ya estuve investigando y si :(... tengo que tene rla variable "lower_case_table_names" seteado en 0 en el servidor viejo, para que al momento de hacer el backup respete el nombre de como estan las tablas :(... El problema es que ese servidor mariadb esta instanciado en un tipo "RDS", pero de HUAWEI y no me permite establecer la config de esa variable :(

puedes hacer esto:
no es la mejor solucion pero en mi caso me funciono
select concat('RENAME TABLE ',table_name, ' TO ', UPPER(table_name),';')
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema ='tu_base_de_datos';

ya luego seria solo seria ejeuctar el resultado.
